# Insert into Red Black Tree

Tags: java, recursion, binary-search-tree, red-black-tree

I want to insert a new node recursively and then return that newly inserted node from function `insertRec` . Function calls look like this

```
    void insert(int value) {       
       root = insertRec(root, null, value);
       root = insertRec(root, null, 15);
       root = insertRec(root, null, 6);
       root = insertRec(root, null, 5);
       root = insertRec(root, null, 3);
       root = insertRec(root, null, 4);
       //insertFixup(newNode);
    }

    RedBlackNode insertRec(RedBlackNode current, RedBlackNode prev, int value)  
    {
       if(current == null) {
         current = new RedBlackNode(value);
         current.p = prev;
       }
       else if(current.key < value) {
         current.right = insertRec(current.right, current, value);
       }
       else {
         current.left = insertRec(current.left, current, value);
       }
       return current;
    }
```

How can I do so while ensuring `insertRec` works correct ? Right now, if I don't return `current` from `insertRec` then I am not able to create tree properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code you don't deal with color of the node which is also important?

Usually for a red-black tree you do the insert in a linear way and not with recursion. Something like:

```
private void insert(int value) {
        RedBlackNode parent = null;
        RedBlackNode current = root;

        while (current!=null){
            parent = current;

            if (value < current.key){
                current = x.left;
                //Here if you store the number of items on the left of a node increase it
            }           
            else{
                current = current.right;
                //Here if you store the number of items on the right  of a node increase it
            }
        }

        RedblackNode newNode=new RedBlackNode(value);

        newNode.p=parrent;

        // Here if parent is null the new node is root of the tree
        //if (parrent==null)
        //      root = newNode;  


        if (value < parent.key)
            parent.left = newNode;
        else
            parent.right = newNode;
        // Usually we add it as RED and then fix the tree to comply with red black tree rules
        newNode.color=(RED);
        fixTree(newNode);
        }
```

It's some pseudo code but that's the idea. You iterate on the tree going down until you reach null. Then you add the new node as RED and then you might need to rotate the tree to fix up the colors.